# Intermittent DNS problems

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns

I have intermittent DNS issues running Windows 7. I tried switching ports on my modem, switching cables and it didn't work. I have Google's DNS servers configured. I'm sure this only happens on my PC since this doesn't happen on my PS4.

My event log shows this:

> Name resolution for the name www.google.com.ar timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.

The weird thing is that before that event there is this:

> The browser has forced an election on network \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{9E97CA55-3E89-4872-9CC6-3683F5F4116F} because a master browser was stopped.

Any idea what this is?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that systems are fighting over who is the master browser role in the workgroup (not on a domain). The following links should prove helpful in resolving the issue.
http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=38701
"Try this key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Browser\Parameters

Edit the MaintainServerList to No"
same on this one 
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r25360544-Windows-Master-Browser-issue

This one says just stop the Browser service altogether, which is what I recommend, as this service is generally not needed in most environments.
http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1020082-losing-connection-every-hour-on-the-hour/